# How to make structural changes in recycler view at runtime. For adding the click to like functionality

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to make Facebook or Instagram like `RecyclerView`. The problem comes when the user taps the like button, no visual changes occur.

`notifyItemChanged()` changes the whole data set after that position.

Comment: What does running notifyDataSetChanged() do?

Comment: What you have tried, what error you got?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't notify adapter that all data changed when you actually changed one item. Use `void notifyItemChanged (int position, Object payload)` on specific item position and then you can retrieve it in void `onBindViewHolder (VH holder, int position, List<Object> payloads)`